# To File::Find is this an array or just a scalar?

Tags: perl, types

In this snippet:

```
find( sub { 
        print "found " . $File::Find::name . "\n";
     }, ("."));
```

What type will the `(".")` be? Array or scalar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's take a look at the parameters for `File::Find::find`. The documentation says:

```
find(\&wanted, @directories_to_search);
```

Let's think of the `find()` function written like this:

```
sub find
{
    my ($wanted, @directories_to_search) = @_;
    ...
}
```

What you need to realize is that the parameters passed to a function are already in list context (a list of scalars): that's the special variable `@_`.  So when you call `find()`, the first argument is assigned to `$wanted`, treated as a coderef (a reference is just a type of scalar). The next variable being assigned to is an array. When you assign a list to an array, the array is "greedy" and takes all values from the list.

So when you assign `@_` to `($wanted, @directories_to_search)`, and all remaining arguments are assigned to `@directories_to_search` (an array of scalars).

Now let's go back to your code. At the highest level, you're calling `find()` by passing a list consisting of two terms:

1. the anonymous coderef `sub { ... }`
2. `"."`: a string of one character in length.

That's like this:

```
my ($wanted, @directories_to_search) = (sub { ... }, ".");
```

So `find()` receives those arguments as I described above: the anonymous coderef is the first argument, and `@directories_to_search` gobbles the rest:

```
my $wanted = sub { ... };
my @directories_to_search = ".";
```

I'm not really sure why you are asking the question (what type is the `(".")` term), but you can make the call to `find()` as you have written it above, or you can remove the extra set of parentheses (they don't add anything).

Comment: I was thinking that if I added paranthesis, Perl would just treat it as an array, just like Python or Ruby do when they encounter brackets.

Comment: @Geo: it's already treated as an array by the called function. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Ether: it's not treated as an array. It's just a list.

Comment: @brian: yes, sorry, poor choice of words. (That might make a good subject for a SO post.)

Answer (score 1):

Read [MJD on context](http://perl.plover.com/context.html).